# Magento2 : How to call CMS page link in PWA

Tags: magento2.3, cms-block, link, pwa-studio

I have Created one CMS page and Added in Static block like below code :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Called static block in `venia-concept/src/components/Footer/footer.js` using below code

```
<div className={classes.footerlink}>
    <CmsBlock area="footer" identifiers={['footer-link']} />
</div>
```

but I am getting below error when click on about link

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/www/html/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/dist/about'`

Answer (score 1):

In Magento2 pwa-studio all the cms page urls will be recognised by pwa-studio RootComponents. you will be able to see output of you cms pages by url :

/cms-page-identifier